# Merging CSV files in Oracle Service Bus (OSB 12c) with same headers

Tags: csv, osb, oracle-service-bus

I want to merge 2 CSV files with same headers (columns) in OSB 12c but unable to figure out a solution. I am very new to this tech so would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!
Regards.

I have created a FTP Adapter that writes a CSV file at a specific location at day end. Issue is another Adapter from another environment also writes a CSV file with the same name at the same location. My Adapter is scheduled to run 1 minute after the other so when my Adapter writes the file, the earlier one gets overwritten as both files have the same name. I am looking for a solution such that both the data get merged into a single CSV file.